# Building reusable libraries with Swift that use bridging headers

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get the hang of Swift, and am beginning by just doing a dumb port of a few applications I've written.

These applications have some core logic in common, for which I've used a Framework target in Xcode to share this with those projects. I'm having trouble coming up with an equivalent in Swift.

I know Swift compiles down to modules, which seems like what I want. I want a Swift module that I can share with my other projects. the major problem I seem to be having though, is that you cannot have a Framework with Swift if it also uses a bridging header starting in Beta 4, which I need to call some APIs (like Security.framework) that don't have Swift bindings. The compiler (Beta 5) fails with this error message:

> `<unknown>:0: error: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported`

What can I do to create a reusable Swift module that also needs to use bridging headers? Alternatively, how can I use things in Security.framework without a bridging header? (Alternatively Aternatively, is there something other than a Framework I should be using to create a module that doesn't have any of these problems?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To import Objective-C code to swift within the same framework target, just import each Objective-C header file in the umbrella header file. Apple's official document has mentioned that already: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_81 see the `Importing Code from Within the Same Framework Target` part.

The cocoa built in frameworks have been migrated as modules in swift. To use the Objective-C's `Security.framework`, you just need to add a line:

```
import Security
```

at the header of the swift file.

Comment: A lot of this information is new since I posted the question. Thanks a lot, I'll look in to it and mark as answer if this works for me.

Comment: applies to .framework dependencies. Any idea about importing static libs? Seems to give the "include of non-modular header inside framework module" build error.